# Embed a wav as3

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I embed a wav into as3/flash builder?

I have:

```
[Embed(source="assets/sounds/claps.wav")]
public var testSound:Class;
private var blahsound:Sound = Sound(new testSound());
```

But no luck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can't](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_02.html). Well, not directly.

> Although there are various sound file formats used to encode digital
>   audio, ActionScript 3.0, Flash Player and AIR support sound files that
>   are stored in the mp3 format. They cannot directly load or play sound
>   files in other formats like WAV or AIFF.

You either need to convert it to an mp3 before embedding it. Or embed it as a ByteArray, and then try to use [`SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html) to fill the sound buffer manually with the bytes from the wav file, but you are going to have to do some finagling.

Comment: Ok, perhaps use mp3's then? What is the best format to use with air? I need a quick response, stuff plays with a lag on android...

Comment: Actually you can, with [As3WavSound]([AS3WavSound](https://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/)) up to a certain point. The library was never finished but still has some basic functionality. Under water it uses the technique you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but hacky. As @32bitkid said, FP doesn't directly support loading sound files other than mp3. The solution is to load the wav as a `ByteArray`, construct a SWF in memory (as using the Flash IDE, you can add wav files), then access the Sound object from this SWF.

Check out http://richapps.de/?p=97

Answer (score 0):

You can try the open source library, [as3wavsound](http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/) (AWS). It supports embedding .wav files and playing them natively.